# JSON is not working

Tags: json, servlets

I have one dropdown in the table.Once I make Onchange event I got all the table value and I want to convert it into json to send it to the servlet.

```
var item = [];
function dropDownOnChange(e) {

var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert("selectedValue:" + selectedValue);
var currentRow= $(e).closest("tr");
var AccountNo = $("td:eq(0)",$(currentRow)).text(); 
alert("accountno"+AccountNo);
var AccountType =$("td:eq(1)",$(currentRow)).text();
alert("acctyp"+AccountType);
var AcctypID = $("td:eq(3)",$(currentRow)).text();
alert("accID"+AcctypID);
```

Here I tried to convert it to JSON. I want to send this JSON value on my final save.

```
var objddlvalue = {};
objddlvalue["AccountNo"] = AccountNo;
objddlvalue["AccountType"] = AccountType;
objddlvalue["Account Type_Val"] = AcctypID;
objddlvalue["AccountStatus"] = selectedValue;
item.push(objddlvalue);
console.log(item);
jsonObj1 = JSON.stringify(item);
console.log(jsonObj1);
```

I am getting my JSON value like:

```
[{
    "AccountNo": "89348734",
    "AccountType": "Credit",
    "Account Type_Val": "21",
    "AccountStatus": "Invalid"
}]
```

When I check on online JSON checker it says the format is correct. But when I access it form servlet I can not parse it to jarray.

```
JSONObject jsonObj1 = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(request.getParameter("jsondata1"));
System.out.println("Json Object........"+jsonObj1.toJSONString());
JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get(jsonObj1);
```

How to loop through my JSON object?

Comment: Since you want to send Json, why do you put it in an array before sending it?

Comment: @alkis.I can be getting more than one Account . Regards,Ruby

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonExternal = "[" + 
                        "{"+
                            "\"AccountNo\": \"89348734\","+
                            "\"AccountType\": \"Credit\","+
                            "\"Account Type_Val\": \"21\","+
                            "\"AccountStatus\": \"Invalid\""+
                        "},"+
                        "{"+
                            "\"AccountNo\": \"89348734_test\","+
                            "\"AccountType\": \"Credit_test\","+
                            "\"Account Type_Val\": \"21_test\","+
                            "\"AccountStatus\": \"Invalid_test\""+
                        "}]";                       

    JSONArray arr = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(jsonExternal);

    for(Object obj : arr) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)obj;

        Collection keySet = jsonObj.keySet();
        Collection entrySet = jsonObj.entrySet();
        Collection values = jsonObj.values();

        for(Object o : keySet) {
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }

        for(Object o : entrySet) {
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }

        for(Object o : values) {
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("AccountNo"));
        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("AccountType"));
        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("Account Type_Val"));
        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("AccountStatus"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @alkis.Thank you. I tried your code but I am getting NullPointerException. Regards,Ruby

Comment: What do you mean by trying? You run as it is or did you try to modify it and plug it with your code. If the latter then something is changed enough to make it crash. Maybe the format of the json you provided is not the right one?

Comment: Please post the json as you receive it on the server.

Comment: I am getting[{ "AccountNo": "89348734",
    "AccountType": "Credit",
    "Account Type_Val": "21",
    "AccountStatus": "Invalid"
}] when I see on console log. Thank you.

Comment: I also guess my format is not correct but when I check in JSON Checker it says correct format:(

Comment: No, I don't mean that the json format is not valid. I mean that the format you posted is not the one that you receive server side. I need you to post the message from the server, not to log it on the client. I want what you receive, not what you send.